# Converting Text to HTML In D

Tags: string, character-encoding, d, text-to-html

I'm trying to figure the best way of encoding text (either 8-bit `ubyte[]` or `string`) to its HTML counterpart.

My proposal so far is to use a lookup-table to map the 8-bit characters

```
string[256] lutLatin1ToHTML;
lutLatin1ToXML[0x22] = "&quot";
lutLatin1ToXML[0x26] = "&amp";
...
```

in HTML that have special meaning using the function

```
pure string toHTML(in string src,
                   ref in string[256] lut) {
    return src.map!(a => (lut[a] ? lut[a] : new string(a))).reduce!((a, b) => a ~ b) ;
}
```

I almost work except for the fact that I don't know how to create a string from a `ubyte? (the no-translation case).

I tried

```
writeln(new string('a'));
```

but it prints garbage and I don't know why.

For more details on HTML encoding see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a string from a ubyte most easily by doing "" ~ b, for example:

```
ubyte b = 65;
string a = "" ~ b;
writeln(a); // prints A
```

BTW, if you want to do a lot of html stuff, my dom.d and characterencodings.d might be useful:
https://github.com/adamdruppe/misc-stuff-including-D-programming-language-web-stuff

It has a html parser, dom manipulation functions similar to javascript (e.g. ele.querySelector(), getElementById, ele.innerHTML, ele.innerText, etc.), conversion from a few different character encodings, including latin1, and outputs ascii safe html with all special and unicode characters properly encoded.

```
assert(htmlEntitiesEncode("foo < bar") == "foo &lt; bar";
```

stuff like that.

Comment: I should probably add that "" ~ 128 won't work - that will probably eventually complain about invalid utf-8 sequence. It won't up front though, so you can build the string one byte at a time. Just make sure you're appending values b < 128 - ascii - or take care to encode the others in proper utf8 format. But if you HTML encode them all, you'll be fine anyway since that's all ascii.

Answer (score 1):

In this case Adam's solution works just fine, of course. (It takes advantage of the fact that ubyte is implicitly convertible to char, which is then appended to the immutable(char)[] array for which string is an alias.)

In general the safe way of converting types is to use std.conv.

```
import std.stdio, std.conv;

void main() {
    // utf-8
    char cc = 'a';
    string s1 = text(cc);
    string s2 = to!string(cc);
    writefln("%c %s %s", cc, s1, s2);

    // utf-16
    wchar wc = 'a';
    wstring s3 = wtext(wc);
    wstring s4 = to!wstring(wc);
    writefln("%c %s %s", wc, s3, s4);    

    // utf-32
    dchar dc = 'a';
    dstring s5 = dtext(dc);
    dstring s6 = to!dstring(dc); 
    writefln("%c %s %s", dc, s5, s6);

    ubyte b = 65;
    string a = to!string(b);
}
```

NB. text() is actually intended for processing multiple arguments, but is conveniently short.

Comment: Indeed, though note that to!string(ubyte) will give a number like "65" rather than A. You could do to!string(cast(char) ubyte), or cast to wchar/dchar too, and that would work.